# Error in BoxCox Transformation - $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, lambda, time-series, transformation

I use R for transforming data using BoxCox function. But i got this error :

```
lambda<-BoxCox.lambda(tsclose3)
lambda
[1] 1.999924
boxcox(tsclose3,lambda = lambda)

**Error in object$y : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**
```

Can u help me to solve this problem?

*tsclose3 is timeseries data, and i have changed it to as.data.frame and as.list but the error still there

```
boxcox(tsclose3,lambda = lambda)
Error in object$y : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
bcclose<-as.list(tsclose3)
lambda<-BoxCox.lambda(bcclose)
Error in BoxCox.lambda(bcclose) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Comment: If the function `BoxCox.lambda` is from the `forecast` package, it takes a vector or object of class `ts` as first argument, so conversion to data frame or list is not going to help. I think your second function should be `BoxCox` from the forecast package, not `boxcox` which is from the MASS package.

Comment: oh right. lol. how stupid i forgot to use capital letter. thank you